# NullPointerException in using overlays on map

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

So Im following the exact instructions as given in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Problem, is when I click on the overlay, it force closes, and logcat shows

```
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:753)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at achint.major.MapItemizedOverlays.onTap(MapItemizedOverlays.java:34)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:346)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:506)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:628)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-21 14:17:46.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1632):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
```

and so on. Why exactly is this happening? I changed the AlertDialog inside the onTap method to a smiple Toast showing some message, but it still gives a problem?

Edit: Sorry, here's the code

```
public class MapItemizedOverlays extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays= new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;


public MapItemizedOverlays(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MapItemizedOverlays(Drawable defaultmarker, Context context){
    super(defaultmarker);
     mContext = context;
     //populate();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index){
    /*OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Test");
    dialog.setMessage("Test");
    dialog.show();*/
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The int caused te problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}

public void addOverlays(OverlayItem overlay){
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
}

}
```

Here's the map activity which is using the overlays:

public class MapDisplay extends MapActivity{

```
private String idValue;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle){

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    MapView mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    idValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("idValue");

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    MapItemizedOverlays itemizedOverlays = new MapItemizedOverlays(drawable);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

    itemizedOverlays.addOverlays(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlays);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), idValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: You have to show the code of MapItemizedOverlays.

Comment: YOu have to different constructor. Can you show how you initialize this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `mContext` is null.

Comment: Yewah, I just realized. What am i supposed to put as the context? When I use MapDisplay.this, then the drawable is not showing up on the map.

Comment: `MapItemizedOverlays itemizedOverlays = new MapItemizedOverlays(drawable, this);`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879159/itemizedoverlay-issues-hellomapview-tutorial for some tips

Comment: Thank you. I tried giving both this and MapDisplay.this as the context. The drawable is absent, although when I click where its supposed to be, the onTap actions is launched. What's wrong witht he context that Im giving?

Comment: Solved, thanks for your help. In case anybody has the same problem, just add the boundCenterBottom(defaultmarker) to every super call as well.